# Mono generating LocalAlloc error while executing the code

Tags: mono, monodevelop, odbc

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and have installed mono, monodevelop 5.10.

Earlier i was working on 14.04 with mono, monodevelop v 4.0.2. My codes were working fine in the earlier version.

In the current version, i am facing problem while retrieving the data from the database using ODBC as LOCALALLOC.

*Note :- Earlier i was getting error while connecting to the database as libodbc.so. to overcome the problem i created a symlink file in the folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu as under
abhinav@cybee-laptop:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ls -l libodbc.so 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jun  8 16:48 libodbc.so -> libodbc.so.2.0.0*

Thereafter I am able to connect the database, but while fetching the data i am getting the error as LocalAlloc

I have cross checked my codes, but it seems to be fine. After going through various links on google I could make out that it is because of some settings required in OS level.

Comment: It seems to be a bug [described here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37368). It happens for me too. I don't know any workarounds yet.